# How to convert list of lists into list of strings in Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Imagine that after reading a file you have a list with this format:

```
>>> data.take(2)
[['Hello ', 'how ', 'are ', 'you'], ['fine ', 'thank ', 'you']]
```

However, you just want to get a list of `strings` such that:

```
['Hello how are you', 'fine thank you']
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply perform a map with `lambda` on the list in question and operate with`join` on each inner list.

```
>>> data = data.map(lambda x : ''.join(x))
>>> data.take(2)
['Hello how are you', 'fine thank you']
```

Answer (score 1):

In Scala we can use mkString to make a list to string

```
val data = List(List("Hello ", "how ", "are ", "you "), List("fine ", "thank ", "you"))
 data.map(_.mkString)
```

Output:

```
List[String] = List("Hello how are you" , "fine thank you")
```

Comment: Output should be this:
`List[String] = List('Hello how are you', 'fine thank you')`

Comment: Thanks you for your answer